# Working with complex json via HTTP request in Angular project (MEAN STACK)

Tags: json, angular, typescript, schema

I'm currently working on a project of my own, and I'm having problems when handling "large" JSON files. I get the data from a MongoDB online (Mongo Atlas), then I access that data through a simple node JavaScript REST API. Given that the complexity of the JSON is large, I'm not sure how to proceed. I normally create a model of the JSON to handle it. But in this case, I don't really know how to do it. The schema is this:

[Swagger documentation](http://www.mingweisamuel.com/lcu-schema/tool/#/Plugin%20lol-match-history/GetLolMatchHistoryV1GamesByGameId)

As you can see it has a lot of nested arrays.
My question is, should I use classes or maybe interfaces? For every array do I need to make a new class?

Currently, this is the model that I was working with:
(this was working on JavaScript, but of course does not work in TypeScript because the object is not truly defined)

```js
    export class Match{
        constructor(
            public _id: string,
            public game: Object
        ){}
    }
```

I know I could import the whole swagger UI to my own project (don't really know how to do it, https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-ts-generator, this might work), but I only really need that one schema.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be frank, when a JSON exceeds a specific length, I really don't use models to handle it (Java side), in fact I'm not using them at all in Angular. It has advantages and also disadvantages, especially when talking about a typescript context, it's not really the recommended thing, but it does the job.

```
  public getData(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(environment.apiBaseUrl + "/data/", this.prepareHeader());
  }
```

Then you actually just `subscribe` on the `Observable` and access the variables you need by their key, e.g.

```
this.dataAcquireService.getData().subscribe(
  (res) => {
    this.data = res;
    for (let i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {
      if (!this.selectGroups[this.data[i].name]) this.selectGroups[this.data[i].name] = [];
      this.selectGroups[this.data[i].name].push(this.data[i]);
    }
  },
  (err) => this.dataAcquireService.handleErrorResponse(err)
)
```

In the end, it's down to taste and expectations because both ways lead to the desired goal, the one might be considered dirty by dogmatists, the other might be considered too tedious.

Comment: Well that was quick! Thx maio290 i'll give it a try and get back if it works for me. I don't really need a clean code, it's a project for myself, as long as i can acces the variables in Angular im good to go.